# C# httpclient factory Readasstringasync sometimes serialized and sometimes not

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I have a weird situation. I am using HttpCLient Factory to make a REST call. Below is my server-side API code.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string PostAPICall([FromBody]Entity Info)
        {
            return "String Value";

        }
```

And from Client I am using HttPClient Factory to make a call

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, input);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var returnValueFromAPI = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Sometimes I have observed it is returning a serialized value(enclosed in doubly escape string) and sometimes it just return simple string. I am not able to understand why it behaving differently on hitting on same call.

Note: My API is hosted on one server, so all call is hitting to the same server and the same code.

Comment: are you sure this isn't just about how you are looking at the value in the debugger?

Comment: yes, I am putting cursor on the variable to see value, I understand sometimes debugger format the text. I have another code that consumes this value and it only failed when it sees a serialized value(doubly escape), I can write some code to deserialize but then it is failing in scenario when it doesn't provide serialized value. I can write some dirty code to handle this scenario but wanted to understand why it is happening.